# Bijective Function between square and circle

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, functions

> Let $r=1$ and let $C$ be the circle with radius $r$ and $S$ the square
>   with sidelength $2r$.
>
> State a bijective function between $C$ and $S$.

Can someone give me a hint in the right direction how to tackle this?

Note that Circle and Square are examplary, what about elipse and triangle, or line and cube?

Comment: Here's one idea: consider describing the position within the circle using polar coordinates.  When doing so for the square with the exception of the four cardinal directions the ray with a particular angle would intersect the square further.  Scale our point back based on the length.  So for example $(1,1)$ on the square would map to $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ on the circle.

Comment: You can find parametric equations for both $S, C$ such that the parametric equations are bijections to intervals on the real line, and the composition of bijections is a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inscribe the circle into the square (note that this can be done perfectly with the circle touching the square at four of the mid points of its sides), rays from the origin will intersect a point on the circle to its corresponding partner on the square. It is easy to see this is a bijection.